# Lightdm appears and immediately disappears (DELL XPS 13)

Tags: 15.04, lightdm, xps

I have this strange problem with LightDM. After booting, the login screen appears... and almost immediately disappears and leaves a black screen.

Mouse cursor is there. If I type in my password (blindly) the login is performed. If I subsequently logout, the interface is visible.

ANy idea??!

Answer (score 0):

Ditched LightDM completely and replaced it with sddm (comes with kubuntu-desktop), since I am mostly using Kubuntu. No problem with this.

By the way, LightDM would prevent me from switching VTs, even after logging in to KDE. Now, using sddm, I have no problems with that, and Ctrl + Alt + Fn will work as expected.